# Why my lambda can't attend the entire queue?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function that sends events to my SQS and another lambda function that serves this SQS. My first lambda sends many events to the SQS, but my second lambda can't catch all events from this SQS.

Normally, my second lambda retrieves thirty out of one hundred events.

The idea is that the second lambda function gets one by one events from my SQS but don't miss the others.

Can anyone give me a tips? Thanks

[SQS config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2jpp.png)
[Lambda config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I27ir.png)

Comment: we need to check batchSize in lambda event source configuration, can you add a screenshot for that?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Yes, added.

Comment: lambda event source bathsize to 1 , so you will get only one event at a time to lambda. I can't think of any other reasons, without looking at actual code.

Comment: Could it be a visibility problem? The lambda gets one by one and the visibility time remove the messages from queue?

Comment: I would disconnect the 2nd Lambda, empty the SQS queue, and then cause the 1st Lambda to send N messages to SQS, then ensure that the SQS queue (with no consumers right now) actually has N message queued. Then attach a trivial consumer Lambda to the SQS queue with batchsize K (less than N) and ensure that it receives all N events. Hopefully this will help you identify which of your Lambda functions is bugged.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, I am going to do some tests and in the future update the comments.

Comment: Guys, the problem was batchSize. I tested all the lambdas and found one that had the wrong batchSize. Thank you for your help!